# Visual Studio Mac Doesn't Recognize Chrome Driver in Path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, macos-high-sierra

I'm new to using C# for Selenium WebDriver. I come from a background using Java and Python on Windows. So I'm also new to OSX, Visual Studio and C#. I've started a project with .NET Application Console, added Selenium packages to NuGet, and downloaded/added ChromeDriver to project path. I'm baffled to as why I'm getting this error.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException has been thrown

"The chromedriver file does not exist in the current directory or in a
directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be 
downloaded at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
index.html."
```

Working with 
Visual Studio 7.5 (build 1254)
macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4

I've also added Chrome Driver path to bash_profile too.

Any help is appreciated. If more information is needed, I won't hesitate to provide :) Thanks!

[IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffFTe.jpg)

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftczf.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put ChromeDriver.exe file inside bin/debug folder.

Further installing instructions at https://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/

Comment: I've added ChromeDriver.exe file to bin debug/folder, save, ran the script and still getting same issue. I've also restarted Visual Studio and re ran the script and still getting same issue.

Comment: Could you add this code and see IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\my\path\to\chromedriver\directory");

Comment: Might help you:  https://www.utest.com/articles/selenium-setup-on-a-mac-and-configuring-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-os

Comment: @Prany I've added the whole path to where my chrome driver is located as you've suggested, but still getting same error from Visual Studio Mac. For some reason the error says that the chrome driver doesn't exist there but I have it there. I have the "chromedriver" (for mac) and "chromedriver.exe" (for windows). I'm using a Mac.

Comment: @PaulLaguna : Oh! It might help. https://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/

Comment: @Prany I got it!! :) :) :) :)
Before I had followed instructions from a guide to add a build path to system variables of:
PATH="/Users/me/path/to/my/chromedriver:${PATH}", but that was incorrect. The build path for my system should be something like:
export PATH=/Users/me/path/to/my/chromedriver:$PATH. Your link to kenst.com gave me the hint. Thanks! I'm still new to Stack Overflow, so I cannot yet vote this as solution until I get more points.

Comment: @PaulLaguna . Cool. You can mark this first comment as answer and I'll add the link for future references

Comment: I copied the chromedriver in the folder you said, and It worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem trying to use `$PATH` in Visual Studio for Mac.  My `$PATH` was configured from within `~/.bash_profile`.  I was able to use chromedriver from [Rider IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) just fine reading the `$PATH` but not Visual Studio for Mac.  Restarted VS and rebooted the machine with no luck.

Finally, I had to drop the chromedriver executable into the solution `bin/TEST` folder because I was running a TEST configuration.  So if `bin/debug` doesn't work for you, you might try `bin/DEV` or `bin/TEST` etc...